# Is there a fast way for drawing counterterm-diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

We have learnt that the Lagrangian in e.g. $\phi^{4}$ can be written as

$$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_{R}+\mathcal{L}_{c.t.}$$

with 
$$\mathcal{L}_{R}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^{2}\phi^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^{4}$$

and

$$\mathcal{L}_{c.t.}=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{Z}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{m}\phi^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\delta_{\lambda}\phi^{4}$$

with $\phi_{0}=\sqrt{Z}\phi$, $m^{2}_{0}=m^{2}+\delta m^{2}$, $\lambda_{0}=\lambda Z_{\lambda}$ and the abbreviations:

$\delta_{Z}=(Z-1)$,

$\delta_{m}=(Z-1)m^{2}+Z\delta m^{2}$ and

$\delta_{\lambda}=Z^{2}Z_{\lambda}-1$

From this, I get the two different vertices for the counterterms, namly the $\phi^{2}$ counterterm vertex with vertex factor $i(p^{2}\delta_{Z}-\delta_{m}$) and the $\phi^{4}$ counterterm vertex with factor $-i\lambda\delta_{\lambda}$....Both counterterm vertices are formaly of order 
$\lambda^{2}$....

But what I have given a much more complicated Lagrangian, like a Lagrangian with more then one field and a variety of interactions....Is there a method for "seeing" which counterterm diagram is needed and which vertex factor correspond to it?

Comment: Just a typo....I have editted the question